# Workaround a sanity filter on push

Tags: git

I have a Git repository on Windows, the origin is on Linux. The following scenario occurs quite frequently:

1. I commit code to my repository
2. I pull the latest changes from the central repository to sync.
3. I'm trying to push, but fail a sanity checker.
4. When I fix the problem I still cannot push, since the hooked checkers seem to check every separate commit, and not only the most up to date code.

E.g., I fixed the problem below in commit 3 after the pull merge, but push keeps failing on commits 1,2:

`remote: [ERR] [user] file xxx.cpp in commit abc failed test TrailingWhitespaceTest`

`remote: [ERR] [user] file xxx.cpp in commit xyz failed test TrailingWhitespaceTest`

I cannot squash 1,2 and 3, since 3 is not adjacent to 1,2. I also cannot modify the origin's hooks.

A solution/workaround would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the hook is looking at each commit you're pushing, you need to fix the problem in the first commit rather than the last one (or any other commit). You can use an interactive rebase to fix, either by stopping for editing the first commit that introduced the problem, or, my preference is to create a new fixup commit on the tip of your branch with the change. Suppose your branch looks like this:

`X-A-B-C-D-E`

Assume `X` is where you branched from (perhaps `main` or similar), and commits `A` through `E` are your new commits. Let's suppose commit `B` is the first commit that introduced the issue. The way to create a fixup commit is:

```
# make the fix and stage it
# create a commit:
git commit -m "squash into B" # this will create a new commit F
# interactive rebase starting from X:
git rebase -i X
# move the bottom commit (F) up to between B and C, and use either "s" or "f"
# Note in this case "f" is probably sufficient since it's a whitespace issue and
# you probably won't need to edit the commit message.
# save and exit
```

If the issue is just whitespace, it's likely that the rebase will continue without conflicts. If later commits modified the same lines though, you'll have to resolve the conflicts as you go.

Since the above steps are so common, Git has a built in helper option for rebase:

```
# make the fix and stage it
# create a commit:
git commit -m "squash into B" --fixup <commit-id-of-B>
# interactive rebase starting from X:
git rebase -i X --autosquash
# save and exit
```

The `--autosquash` simply looks for specially named commit messages and automatically rearranges the commits for you in the interactive rebase TODO list.

**Side Note:** It might be helpful to see if you can get a copy of the hook locally so you are warned when creating your commits.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to Git, and wasn't aware of the option to change the commit order using `rebase`.